# Formatting tables in Swift documentation comments

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a section of code like this sitting above my computed property:

```
 /**     
 Data Types Conversions:
 -----------------------
 +-----------------+-------------+
 | kernel          | Swift/Obj-c |
 +=================+=============+
 | sampler         | CISampler   |
 | __table sampler | CISampler   |
 | __color         | CIColor     |
 | float           | NSNumber    |
 | vec2/3/4        | CIVector    |
 +-----------------+-------------+
 */
```

When it is rendered in the formatted comments pop-up I see garbled text.

Is there a way to represent this data in a table that actually renders when you option-click on the associated computed property?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with a code indent.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any code markup for tabular formatting like that. I suggest you check Apple's site on their code documentation format:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/Throws.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH26-SW1

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without indenting by using a "fenced" code block, surrounding your table (or code block) by triple backticks (```), the same way it works on stack overflow. But indenting may be cleaner and save vertical space.